# Cannot use object as a type of method's default parameter

Tags: c#, object, default-parameters

My code looks like this

```
static void SomeVoid(object obj1, object ojb2 = someDefaultValue) {
    // Do Something Here
}
```

the compiler says that Default parameter value for the 'obj2' must be a compile-time constant.
what can I do ? someDefaultValue is `string.Empty` in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change parameter type to `string`, and use empty string instead:

```
static void SomeVoid(object obj1, string ojb2 = "") {
    // Do Something Here
}
```

Compiler is complaining, because default parameter value will be provided during compilation in place where your method is called. I.e. when you write

```
Foo.SomeVoid(42);
```

It would compile into

```
Foo.SomeVoid(42, "");
```

That's why default parameter value should be constant value. Also parameter type should be `string`, because all reference type parameters can be initialized with `null` constant only. And `object` is a reference type.

---

There is workaround for you. You can use parameter of `object` type with default value `null` and handle that value manually inside your method:

```
static void SomeVoid(object obj1, object obj2 = null) {

    if (obj2 == null)
        // use default value

    // Do Something Here
}
```

Comment: I tried that and then i had two errors, one of which is the same error i get and another says that obj2 is of type object. A default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null. I even tried ojbect obj2 = (object)string.empty and evern object obj2 = (object)"". nothing seems to work

Comment: obj2 is of type object. A default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null

Comment: @Dima change parameter type to `string` or handle null value manually

Comment: Note that the second workaround here _slightly_ changes behaviour. In the old code, you could explicitly pass a `null` value and not have it converted to `String.Empty`. Now you cannot pass `null` without it being forcibly converted to `String.Empty`. Probably not an issue though in this case.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair completely agree with you. I'd better go with changing parameter type to `string`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I agree too _if_ the second parameter is supposed to be a string. If any `object` could be passed in, it's changing the signature. If Dima _intended_ for strings to be passed in, then it should be `SomeVoid(object, string)` 100%.

Answer (score 5):

You might just use a standard overload:

```
static void SomeVoid(object obj1) {
    SomeVoid(obj1, String.Empty);
}

static void SomeVoid(object obj1, object ojb2) {
    // Do Something Here
}
```

This also gives you the benefit that if you decide the default value shouldn't be `String.Empty`, you can change it without forcing callers to recompile to pass in the new default value. The other solutions have *subtle* differences in how they are called or behave; I think using an overload like this is the best way to ensure the exact same behaviour. (that said, if `obj2` is *supposed* to be a `string`, I would totally go with @lazyberezovsky's answer)

Comment: yeah, that's probably what I'll do

Answer (score 1):

```
static void SomeVoid(object obj1, object ojb2 = null) {
    ojb2 = ojb2 ?? someDefaultValue;

    // Do Something Here
}
```

Comment: I don't think `const object someDefaultValue = new Object()` will compile for the same reason: can only initialize a constant reference type other than `string` to `null`.

Comment: yep. won't compile. removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. The error message describes clearly: "A default parameter value of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null".

And you can not use "" either.

I would simply go by:

```
static void SomeVoid(object obj1, object obj2 = null)
{
    obj2 = obj2 ?? "";
    // rest
}
```